# Sampling calculation on based IDs in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been facing an issue while taking sample from an ID of a table. If I sample it over the whole population then getting improper results, and getting count 3 on CLI_1 and count 0 for CLI_2, when I sample with .1 mean. For example -

**Table create query :**

```
CREATE
OR
REPLACE temp TABLE tmp.cg_test AS
SELECT
        column1::varchar ID          ,
        column2::boolean sample_flag ,
        column3::varchar term_id
FROM
        ( VALUES
        ('ID_1', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_2', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_3', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_4', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_5', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_6', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_7', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_8', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_9', NULL, 'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_10', NULL,'CLI_1'),
        ('ID_11', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_12', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_13', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_14', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_15', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_16', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_17', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_18', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_19', NULL,'CLI_2'),
        ('ID_20', NULL,'CLI_2')
        );
```

**Sampling Query:**

```
          CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE tmp.sample_calc_cli AS 
     Select id,
        uniform(0::float, 1::float, random(1))  AS random_val,
       --  uniform(0::float, 1::float, random(1)) OVER (PARTITION  BY term_id) AS cli_sampling_value,
     (uniform(0::float, 1::float, random(1))<.1)::boolean  AS sample_flag,
       -- ((uniform(0::float, 1::float, random(1)) < 0.1) OVER (PARTITION  BY term_id))::boolean as sample_flag,    -- error
         term_id
         from tmp.cg_test  
     GROUP BY id, term_id ORDER BY term_id asc;
```

**Count check for sample:**

```
 SELECT term_id,
 count(term_id) AS total_cli,
 count_if(sample_flag= true) AS sample_count
 FROM tmp.sample_calc_cli GROUP BY term_id;
```

**Result**

| TERM_ID | TOTAL_CLI | SAMPLE_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CLI_1 | 10 | 3 |
| CLI_2 | 10 | 0 |

Uncommenting partitioning with uniform() populates an error as :

```
SQL Error [2060] [42601]: SQL compilation error:
Invalid function type [UNIFORM] for window function.
```

What could be the possible way to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You just calculate random values, to randomly pick rows from the table. If you use 23 as the seed number, you can see that you get 2 samples from CLI_2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE sample_calc_cli AS 
     Select id,
        uniform(0::float, 1::float, random(23))  AS random_val,
     (uniform(0::float, 1::float, random(23))<.1)::boolean  AS sample_flag,
         term_id
         from cg_test  
     GROUP BY id, term_id ORDER BY term_id asc;
```

If you need to pick equal number of sample rows, you may use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sample_calc_cli
qualify row_number() over (partition by term_id order by random() ) < 3;
```

This one will pick 2 rows for each term_id.

Comment: Thanks @Gokhan Atil. Does this seed value need to be changed as per data size? For example, currently I'm trying to sample with only 20 rows but in reality these rows can be in millions.

Comment: The seed number is not important for the row_number method. For the first one, I don't think there is a magical seed number that helps you to pick "enough" rows from all IDs.

Comment: yea but uniform randomness being calculated for whole population in one go rather than  assigning to different partitions based on IDs. This random function will calculate more values near to mean value in small data counts, I think.